# jquery wont preload radio buttons in IE 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, input, radio-button

I am trying to pre-fill a form with data that was retrieved from a jquery AJAX call.  The data is coming in fine but i cant get the proper radio buttons checked when using IE 7.

The following code works fine in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome

```
Lets assume data.description = 'student'

// I have tried both of these with no luck in IE 7
$("input[value='"+data.description+"']").attr('checked', true);
$("input[name='self_description']").filter("[value='"+data.description+"']").attr('checked', true);

<div><label><input type="radio" name="description" value="student">student</label></div>
<div><label><input type="radio" name="description" value="part time">part-time</label></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter expression seems to be missing an opening square bracket, and literals should be quoted. Try:

```
$("input[name='self_description']").filter("[value='"+data.description+"']").attr('checked', true);
```

EDIT:

The only other thing that springs to mind, is to execute that once the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: The jquery is in a function that is called via the document.ready

Comment: @peledies - Have you tried properly quoting `data.description`? `.filter("[value='"+data.description+"']")`

Comment: Good suggestion, but that doesn't resolve it.  I should point out that this method works fine for checkboxes.